# PDF for Xamarin Forms

Tags: pdf, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

When it opens the pdf viewer, it does not show the pdf, check that it had route and everything, but I do not know because reason does not show it.

I am working with UWP in Xamarin Forms.

My reference : [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/display-pdf/)

Download the pdf before displaying, so I do not believe that it does not exist, if not leave error or null.

[My application with visor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSFMN.png)

Comment: Could show me the path of PDF file?

Comment: I would try opening the pdf with Device.OpenUri to prove the issue is not the path or the pdf did not download properly.